Vite React not working on Xampp localhost
I am using Tailadmin react which is configured using VITE. I'm trying to run the build files locally on Xampp but it only shows white screen.
When I try npm run build and npm run preview it works perfectly fine.
But it seems like there's no way to make this working in xampp.
Here is my vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  base: '/react-admin-dashboard-html/', // Use a relative base URL
});

and App.tsx
import { Suspense, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Route, Routes, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

import Loader from './common/Loader';
import PageTitle from './components/PageTitle';
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard';
import Masters from './pages/Masters';

function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [pathname]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setLoading(false), 1000);
  }, []);

  return loading ? (
    <Loader />
  ) : (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          index
          element={
            <>
              <PageTitle title="Dashboard | Medical Solutions" />
              <Dashboard />
            </>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/masters"
          element={
            <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
              <Masters />
            </Suspense>
          }
        />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

there seems something wrong with routes because when I deploy without routes for testing it works fine.
And here's .htaccess file in xampp
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /react-admin-dashboard-html/
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /react-admin-dashboard-html/index.html [L]
</IfModule>

